# Pointing a service to a subdirectory using Cloudflare Zero Access provides a 404 error

Tags: routing, cloudflare

I'm working with my friend to get some of my services on a subdirectory. Essentially, instead of having service.example.com you have example.com/service.

I have installed cloudflared with an authorized token onto a Debian server as a service, and that is tunneling those ports onto cloudflare, which I have had my friend set up to point a specific port to a subdirectory.

I'm not using a reverse proxy, as I haven't needed to.

According to the (most likely outdated) tutorials we've seen it should tunnel the info coming from that port to the subdirectory, but it instead gives a 404 error after trying and failing to load a subfolder.

> [404 error, seemingly generated with HttpErrorPages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd7Y2.png)

I have extensively checked the preferences on my side and on their side, and I've looked through plenty of threads to find something similar.